# "Not authorized to access the application ID" when try to access Licence API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

here's current code:

```
SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license'
]

def getAppService():
  CREDENTIALS_ = appengine.AppAssertionCredentials(scope=SCOPES)
  http = httplib2.Http(memcache)
  http = CREDENTIALS_.authorize(http)
  service = discovery.build(serviceName = 'appsmarket', version='v2', http=http)
  return service

def getLicenseNotifications():
  service = getAppService()
  ret = service.licenseNotification().list(applicationId='THE_PROJECT_ID_NUMBER', timestamp=0, max_results=10).execute()
  logging.debug(ret)
  return ret
```

but it got 403 with "Not authorized to access the application ID". this code was called from GAE project as the default builtin service account, under the same project with the exact same project id where the marketplace app's manifest.json api_console_project_id field.

I did search with the error message, but got non-related info.

the "Google Apps Marketplace API" is certainly ON in developer console.

if I replace 'v2' to 'v2sandbox', it seems timeout then report Backend error.

any help?

Comment: The applicationId='THE_PROJECT_ID_NUMBER' has your app id correct? You just removed it for the post? It might also be easier to use the decorator. Its wraps a lot of what your doing. https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/

Comment: And this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoUdWBzUZ-M

Comment: Yes, I replaced my project number to THE_PROJECT_ID_NUMBER. And thank you I did watched the video days ago and currently I'm using the decorator, but it ask for approve auth for each new user, it's not recommend by marketplace best practices, I did use the decorator with webapp accessing user's oauth token to access google directory api. I doubt it can be used for the marketplace license api, because I don't think the marketplace license api is open for anyone. On the other hand, we suppose can use the GAE service account to do that, but I get stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the GAE default service account, which does not supported by the marketplace api I guess. if I create a standalone service account and use SignedJwtAssertionCredentials load it, and use the only license scope, it works. so the GAE default service account was not supported by the merketplace api.

and for google apps installed app, it already grant the app to access as any user of the domain to specified scopes. but which need we add a "sub=" param in the SignedJwtAssertionCredentials init param to tell the library which domain user we want to act as. so, by this, as long as we know an admin user of a domain, then we can just act as the user to access the directory api without popup any auth screen to final user. and this is not supported by the default GAE service account either.